# rxjs-compat vs pipe() method

Tags: angular, rxjs

I used to chain methods with Observable like

```
Observable
.of('bla')
.map(text => 1)
.filter(value => value === 1)
.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

But now, I realize that since angular V6, we should use pipe() method like

```
Observable.of('bla').pipe(
map(text => 1),
filter(value => value === 1)
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

As I saw lot of code that uses pipe(), I suppose I should use it, but is it really 'mandatory' ? or rxjs-compat will do the trick ?

Comment: rxjs-compat is a temporary measure to let you use rxjs6+ with libraries that haven't migrated yet. But all libraries have migrated for a long time. It's your turn now. As far as I remember, upgrading using the CLI upgrade tool will migrate your code automatically.

Comment: And the new version is `of('bla')` not `Observable.of('bla')`

Comment: @JBNizet maybe you can also give pointers on how to migrate?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/#5.2:8.0

Answer (score 5):

[RxJS compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) is nothing but a backward-compatibility layer that eases the update/migration process from RxJS 5 to RxJS 6. You should not rely on `RxJS compat` for any long term development, but instead, slowly upgrade your codebase which utilises any RxJS operators. You may read more about the [migration guide](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration) for more details.

In RxJS 6, RxJS operators are now chained using `pipe()` utility (rather than dot chaining), hence they are also known as pipeable operators.

Since you are using Angular, I would recommend you to check out the Angular [update guide](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:8.0) too, which includes a series of steps to update your Angular and RxJs versions.

In addition, `Observable.of()` has been replaced by the `of()` operator in RxJS 6.

```
of('bla')
  .pipe(
    map(text => 1),
    filter(value => value === 1)
  ).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```